# React-Navigation Push replaces the previous screen data

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `navigation.push` for navigate to same screen with different parameters, It replaces the previous all screens data by recently pushed screen

My Stack Root

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name='ViewProduct'
        component={ViewProduct}
        options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          headerTitle: props => <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold'}}>Product Details</Text>,
        })}
        />
```

My Product view screen

```
<TouchableOpacity delayPressIn={500} onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.push('ViewProduct',{"uid":item.uid}))}>
     <View>
           <Image style={styles.prodImage} source={{uri:IMG_URL+'/images'+item.image_base_path+item.image_variant+'/m/'+item.cover_image}}/>                      
      </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Needed Approach

```
In navigation.push

product-1 >> product-2 >> product-3 >> product-4

In goback

product-1 << product-2 << product-3 << product-4
```

Current Issue

```
In navigation.push

product-1 >> product-2 >> product-3 >> product-4

In goback

product-4 << product-4 << product-4 << product-4
```

Comment: Push doesn't replace previous screen's data. Can you create a snack? Though for your use case, you can also use `navigate` + `getId` (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **navigation.navigate('yourscreen')**. This produces your expected output. Use as below mentioned.

```
=> this.props.navigation.navigate('FirstScreen); 
=> this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen'); 
=> this.props.navigation.navigate('ThirdScreen');
```

**Don't use** any **push()** or **dispatch()** method. For navigation if it is a class based use below method.

Example:

> this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen');

If it is a functional component import **useNavigation** props from **@react-navigation/native**. Please have a look at this below example.

Example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function GoToButton({ screenName }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title={`Go to ${screenName}`}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't want to navigate to different screen, i want to navigate the same screen with only different parameters, for example product view screen has different color variants for the same product, So when we touch on the image it will trigger to open a new screen to show the selected color of the product, this approach is working fine but we go back to previous screen, it still shows the last selected product details